# Display count of records for each category

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, aggregate-functions

I am new to forum and please bear with me and do let me know if there is anything unclear. Thank you.

> Table: BB_BB60_COURSE_MAIN
>
> Field used: BATCH_UID, COURSE_ID
>
> Criteria: COURSE_ID that contains keyword "2018"

---

> Table: BB_BB60_COURSE_USERs
>
> Field used: ROLE, ROW_STATUS
>
> Criteria: ROLE = "S" (student), ROW_STATUS = 0 (enabled)

---

> Table: BB_BB60_USERS
>
> Field used: USER_ID

I need to run query for two different approaches.

1. List number of student enrolment (enabled) per each courseID in year 2018
2. List number of course enrolment (enabled) per each userID (student) in year 2018

I have done the query for the first one

```
SELECT 
    BB_BB60_COURSE_MAIN.BATCH_UID, 
    BB_BB60_COURSE_MAIN.COURSE_ID, 
    BB_BB60_COURSE_USERS.ROW_STATUS, 
    BB_BB60_COURSE_USERS.ROLE, 
    Count(BB_BB60_COURSE_USERS.USERS_PK1) AS NoOfEnrol
FROM 
    (BB_BB60_COURSE_USERS INNER JOIN BB_BB60_COURSE_MAIN ON BB_BB60_COURSE_USERS.CRSMAIN_PK1 = BB_BB60_COURSE_MAIN.PK1) 
    INNER JOIN BB_BB60_USERS ON BB_BB60_COURSE_USERS.USERS_PK1 = BB_BB60_USERS.PK1
WHERE 
    (((BB_BB60_COURSE_MAIN.COURSE_ID) Like "%2018%") AND 
    ((BB_BB60_COURSE_USERS.ROLE)="S") AND 
    ((BB_BB60_COURSE_USERS.ROW_STATUS)=0))
GROUP BY 
    BB_BB60_COURSE_MAIN.BATCH_UID, BB_BB60_COURSE_MAIN.COURSE_ID, 
    BB_BB60_COURSE_USERS.ROW_STATUS, BB_BB60_COURSE_USERS.ROLE
ORDER BY 
    BB_BB60_COURSE_MAIN.COURSE_ID;
```

This is part of the result:

```
BATCH_UID       COURSE_ID      ROW_STATUS    ROLE        NoOfEnrol
13july_2018_T2  13july_2018_T2     0          S             3
149301_2018_FY  149301_2018_FY     0          S             1
210011_2018_01  210011_2018_01     0          S             1
210011_2018_02  210011_2018_02     0          S             7
410401_2018_02  410401_2018_02     0          S             19
510151_2018_02  510151_2018_02     0          S             10
510998_2018_FY  510998_2018_FY     0          S             234
516001_2018_01  516001_2018_01     0          S             28
516009_2018_01  516009_2018_01     0          S             1
516024_2018_02  516024_2018_02     0          S             20
516557_2018_01  516557_2018_01     0          S             12
```

I am stuck in the second query, can anyone help with this? 
Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 2nd query would be:

```
SELECT  
    BB_BB60_COURSE_USERS.USER_ID,
    BB_BB60_COURSE_USERS.ROW_STATUS, 
    BB_BB60_COURSE_USERS.ROLE, 
    Count(BB_BB60_COURSE_MAIN.COURSE_ID) AS NoOfEnrol
FROM 
    (BB_BB60_COURSE_USERS INNER JOIN BB_BB60_COURSE_MAIN ON BB_BB60_COURSE_USERS.CRSMAIN_PK1 = BB_BB60_COURSE_MAIN.PK1) 
    INNER JOIN BB_BB60_USERS ON BB_BB60_COURSE_USERS.USERS_PK1 = BB_BB60_USERS.PK1
WHERE 
    (((BB_BB60_COURSE_MAIN.COURSE_ID) Like "%2018%") AND 
    ((BB_BB60_COURSE_USERS.ROLE)="S") AND 
    ((BB_BB60_COURSE_USERS.ROW_STATUS)=0))
GROUP BY 
    BB_BB60_COURSE_USERS.USER_ID, 
    BB_BB60_COURSE_USERS.ROW_STATUS, BB_BB60_COURSE_USERS.ROLE
ORDER BY 
    BB_BB60_COURSE_MAIN.COURSE_ID;
```